# CSS reference to text inside element but not to text's adjacent div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the following example, how do I hide the "Text I want hidden" without hiding the div labeled "Content that needs to be visible"?

```html
<section>
    <div>Content that needs to be visible</div>
    <a href="#">Link I want hidden</a>
    Text I want hidden
</section>
```

Referencing anything with a tag assigned to it is obviously easily referenced; I just can't figure out how hide text within the `<section>` and keep the `<div>` visible.

If I apply `<style> section :not(div) { display: none; } </style>`, all that gets hidden is the `<a>` tag; the text I want hidden remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really apply `display: none` to just a text node without it being wrapped in something but you can do a workaround with `font-size`. Note: this might produce accessibility problems as a screen reader will think the text is still there even if it's not displayed.

Ideally wrap your text in a `span` or similar but if you can't change your html this is an option.

```css
section {
  font-size:0;
}

section > div {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>Content that needs to be visible</div>
    <a href="#">Link I want hidden</a>
    Text I want hidden
</section>
```